# list<int> showing null

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-2

```
string[] baChildrenIds = ids.Split(',');
                    List<int> intList = new List<int>();
                    foreach (var id in baChildrenIds)
                    {
                        intList.Add(Convert.ToInt32(id));
                    }
                    List<int> tempList = new List<int>();
                    if (Session["SelectedList"] != null)
                    {
                        var temp = Session["SelectedList"] as List<int>;
                        tempList.AddRange(temp);
                    }
                    Session["SelectedList"] = tempList.Union(intList);
```

Initial Add I am adding two Integer values to the Session. second time I am adding three integer values to the Session.

when I am accessing the Session something like this I am allways getting null.

```
 var temp = Session["SelectedList"] as List<int>;
```

Could any body help me out? how to get all the session values as list?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

when you assign the session your session become 
`System.Linq.Enumerable.UnionIterator<int>` type and when you access the session you convert it in `List<int>` which is not match so it gives the error.

you have to write like as follow so you can get the value

```
if (Session["SelectedList"] != null)

  {

  List<int> ls = (List<int>)Session["SelectedList"];           
  var temp = ls;

  tempList.AddRange(temp);
  }

Session["SelectedList"] = tempList.Union(intList).ToList();
```

Comment: when answering a question, you might format the text (there are some buttons for formatting, the one for code is {}, just select the text, then click on {})

Answer (score 3):

The List class doesn't have a Union method. That method is coming out of the LINQ extensions, and it returns IEnumerable in your case. IEnumerable is not a list. If you were using a cast rather than "as" you would have seen a runtime error. All you need to do is tack .ToList() onto the end of the last line.

Comment: I should also add that you don't really need two lists here. If you swap positions on your two code clauses you could do it with just one list.

Comment: But I am getting the Problem in this line.var temp = Session["SelectedList"] as List<int>;

Answer (score 2):

The `as` operator returns null if the cast fails.

In your case `Session["SelectedList"]` isn't of type `List<int>`, so `null` is being returned.

The call to `.Union` isn't returning a `List<int>`, but an `IEnumerable<int>` instead.  Call `.ToList()` to convert it to a `List<int>`

Answer (score 2):

```
Session["SelectedList"] = tempList.Union(intList).ToList();
```

[Union](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb341731.aspx) method returns IEnumerable, not List.

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 2):

The Union Linq operation returns an IEnumerable. When assigning your session variable try this instead:

```
Session["SelectedList"] = tempList.Union(intList).ToList();
```